# Admin user can't enable contained database SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-rds

I created an RDS SQL Server instance, and logged in with the provided admin username.

But I can't seem to enable contained database with the following command

```
EXEC sp_configure 'contained database authentication', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Gives me a permission error, I also found out that only two user roles can enable the contained database feature which is sysadmin and serveradmin. I tried adding admin as a member of the sysadmin role with the command:

```
ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER admin ;  
GO
```

Still get a permission error, is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if AWS disables that in their deployment. [REF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/contained-database-authentication-server-configuration-option)  When contained databases are enabled, database users with the ALTER ANY USER permission, such as members of the db_owner and db_accessadmin database roles, can grant access to databases and by doing so, grant access to the instance of SQL Server. ...more at the link...

Comment: Correct. Amazon RDS does not grant full Sysadmin permission to users, since AWS is acting as the sysadmin.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning seen, I guessed this was the case. I'm still trying to find workarounds about enabling contained databases.

Answer (score 0):

When using AWS RDS, you manage your database engine configuration through the use of parameters in a database parameter group.

AWS RDS restricts access to certain system procedures and tables that require advanced privileges. Amazon RDS supports access to databases on an instance using any standard SQL client application, but some system tools, like `sp_configure` are not available as a way to set server-level settings. We can run `sp_configure` and see the configuration values, but we can’t change them directly in SQL Server.

There is a parameter group option called: `contained database authentication` that will help you.